# Joint::GetLinkForce() gets segmentation fault

Tags: ros, gazebo, joint, gazebo-plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Has anybody used Joint::GetLinkForc() or Joint::GetLinkTorque in gazebo simulator?
I am using them in a gazebo plugin and these functions give me segmentation fault.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42069/joint::getlinkforce()-gets-segmentation-fault/) by [Zara](https://answers.ros.org/users/2831/zara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2012-08-23**:
yeah, I made a post about this awhile back, http://answers.ros.org/question/40678/gazebo-plugin-get-total-force-on-joint/  follow the link in that post to another question where HSU talks about some of this.  I assume everything he said there is still valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ticketed [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/16/joint-getlinkforce-joint-getlinktorque).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1